# Java onClick from js

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

I am creating html button from js and inject via java. I want that this button change activity. That my code.

```
public class WebsiteActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button btnActTwo;
//...

private class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void clickBtnActTwo() {
        btnActTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActTwo);
        btnActTwo.setOnClickListener(WebsiteActivity.this);
        Log.e("TEST","TEST");
    }
//...

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            String javascript = "javascript:"
                    + "function onClickBtnActTwo() {Android.clickBtnActTwo();}"
                    + "var btnacttwo = document.createElement('div');"
                    + "btnacttwo.innerHTML = 'BtnAcTwo text';"
                    + "btnacttwo.onclick = onClickBtnActTwo;"
                    + "element = document.getElementsByClassName('contentMenu')[0];"
                    + "element.appendChild(btnacttwo);"
            view.loadUrl(javascript);
//...

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnActTwo:
            Log.e("TEST2","TEST2");
            Intent btnActTwoIntent = new Intent(this, BtnActTwoActivity.class);
            startActivity(btnActTwoIntent);
            break;
//...
```

Generally in console I see TEST tag, when I push dynamically created div button, but not TEST2. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. If I push button that created via java it works. How can I implement this to work from injected js?

Comment: You most likely don't set the onClickListener

Comment: Can you please add example, i dont understand

Comment: if you don't set the onClickListener, it isn't going to work. It is a method that requires registration (through calling `setOnClickListener` on a View)

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? Is you onClickListener goes to the onClick method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it myself. Just done this directly from Intent. Maybe this will help someone.

```
private class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void clickBtnActTwo() {
        //...
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, AdsActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

But i really dont understand, what i done wrong with setOnClickListener